# Is there any curried change's on haskell?

Tags: haskell

Im studying from a book curried on haskell and I read that If I use this partially applying function with 9 it should results LT, but is GT as u can see. I also used 800 to prove that. If I'm understanding in a bad way pls correct me.

[Curried example of compare function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnswB.png)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why should it result in `LT`?

Comment: Please put the actual code you're running directly in the question. Links can provide helpful context, but it should be possible to understand and answer your question without following the link.

Answer (score 2):

`compareWithHundred` is the same as `compare 100`, so
`compareWithHundred 9` is the same as `(compare 100) 9`,
which is GT because 100 > 9.